# how many cases are appropriate on a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I plan to group my JS code by switch statement. It gonna be over 50 cases, I guess.

Is this too many cases? If my concern was right, how many cases should a switch statement handle?

**//Edit**

Just in case of fancybox, I want to group them by using switch statement within a function, like this:

```
function openFancybox(object){
    switch(object)
    {
        case '.edit':
            width = 900;
            height = 400;
        break;

        case '.friend':
            width = 700;
            height = 300;
        break;

        case '.follow':
            width = 'auto';
            height = 'auto';
        break;

        case '.global':
            width = 'auto';
            height = 'auto';
        break;

    }
    $(object).fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'centerOnScroll'    : true,
        hideOnOverlayClick:false,
        hideOnContentClick:false,
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'centerOnScroll'    : true,
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
    });
}
```

Comment: What do your cases contains ?

Comment: It should be possible to do it differently. Have you considered having a dictionary/map of key-to-value, where the key is the case and the value could be whatever info you return from that function, or a reference to a function?

Comment: Please rephrase the question, adding more details (some code, or at least the (high-level) description of it). As it stands, your question is way too abstract - hence the closing vote and -1 from me.

Comment: Im' sorry about that. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case I'd have chosen the map (JS Object) solution, with keys being the classNames, and values being the arrays (of [width, height]) structure. For example:

```
var fancyBoxSettings = {
  edit: [900, 400],
  friend: [700, 300],
  some: [42, 42],
  more: [420, 420]
};
```

... minimizing the duplicating code (all these `width =, height =`, `break` etc.). Then I would have managed retrieving of these values with a helper function:

```
function getFancyBoxDimensions(className) {
  var dimensions = fancyBoxSettings[className] || ['auto', 'auto'];
  return { width: dimensions[0], height: dimensions[1] };
}
```

So it can be used like this:

```
var fbxSettings = {
  titlePosition     : 'inside',
  transitionIn      : 'none',
  transitionOut     : 'none'
  // ...
};
$.extend(fbxSettings, getFancyBoxDimensions(className)); 
$('.' + className).fancybox(fbxSettings);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your method really impresses me. I've just implemented and it works perfectly. I've been wondering about that for a long time and finally it has a perfect solution. Thanks again!